# POST request for many to many in express

Tags: node.js, rest, express, post, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables: user and material which have a m:m relationship. The intersection entity is journalMaterials. I am trying to send a POST request to insert into journalMaterials. Also, this table has 2 attributes: recycledQuantity and recycleDate. I tried something, but if i insert with a materialId which doesn't exist it doesn't give me "not found".

```
 app.post('/users/:uid/materials/:mid', (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.params.uid)
    .then((user) => {
      if (user){
        let journalMaterial = req.body
        journalMaterial.userId = user.id
        Material.findById(req.params.mid)
         .then((material) => {
           if (material){
            journalMaterial.materialId = material.id
            return JournalMaterial.create(journalMaterial)
           }
           else{
        res.status(404).send('not found')
      }
         })}
      else{
        res.status(404).send('not found')
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      if (!res.headers){
        res.status(201).json('created')
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err))
})
```

Comment: *"if i insert a materialId which doesn't exist it doesn't give me 'not found'"* - yeah, that's exactly what the code you have here will do.

Comment: the thing is, if it looks in the db for a material with id 2 for eg and it doesn't find one, it should enter else branch, give not found and exit, but i don't understand why he doesn't do that...

Comment: I misread, I thought you said you *were* getting `not found` - so what *does* happen?

Comment: to be more clear, i insert an user with userId=1 and a material with materialId=1, so i don't have any more users or materials, so if i send my POST method with userId=1 and materialId=2 i should get "not found", because i don't have a material with materialId=2, but instead i get "created" and the server gives the error: "Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. Here is the correct code.

```
app.post('/users/:uid/materials/:mid', (req, res, next) => {
      const { uid, mid } = req.params;
      Promise.all([
        User.findById(uid),
        Material.findById(mid)
      ])
        .then(([user, material]) => {
          if (user && material) {
            let journalMaterial  = req.body
            journalMaterial.userId = user.id
            journalMaterial.materialId = material.id
            res.status(201).json('created')
            return JournalMaterial.create(journalMaterial)
          }
          res.status(404).send('not found')
        })
        .catch(err => next(err));
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly re-wrote this to make it a bit more readable.  Removed your nested promise calls... (let's not dive into promise hell when they try to get rid of callback hell..)

```
app.post('/users/:uid/materials/:mid', (req, res, next) => {
  const { journalMaterial } = req.body;
  const { uid, mid } = req.params;
  Promise.all([
    User.findById(uid),
    Material.findById(mid)
  ])
    .then(([user, material]) => {
      if (user && material) {
        journalMaterial.userId = user.id;
        journalMaterial.materialId = material.id;
        return JournalMaterial.create(journalMaterial);
      }
      res.status(404).send('not found');
    })
    .then(() => {
      if (!res.headers) {
        res.status(201).json('created');
      }
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
});
```

Your check against `if(user)` currently passes.  It seems that if that's what is happening, you're always getting an object back.  Lots of databases generally don't simply return a `null` or `false` value, but rather an object with a bunch of meta data.  In that object is generally the data you requested (ie, user.data.id, but it may be that user.data is NULL).  Can you verify what the exact contents of `Users` is?  It's evaluating to truthy, thus it must have something in it.

Comment: thank you for rewriting it! it is more nicely, but unfortunately it gives me the error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'userId' of undefined
    at Promise.all.then"

Comment: Then that is because your "journalMaterial" doesn't exist on your request body

Comment: thanks! i declared let journalMaterial=req.body after the first if. Now, if i give ids that don't exist it gives me "not found", which is fine, but it also gives me an error in server: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see what is actually going on?  Try doing that first :)  It will most definitely show you what's going on.